# A single digital certificate for a development group?

Tags: digital-certificate

We have a small development group that has a need to use ClickOnce to deploy some intranet applications.  Would it be proper for the group to use a single digital certificate for these deployments, or should each developer have their own certificate? (I haven't been able to find anything definitive on this subject.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your scope but professional applications usually get signed by a trusted third-party e.g. `Verisign`.